# b-table render all the data without respecting the fields

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, production-environment

I am building a project using laravel and Vue JS to create a list of companies with pagination etc..

I am using bootstrap-table and the problem the table render all the data without respecting the fields that I am giving as a param. I want to use scope field to show a custom css inside every row. I use the same table with other data it works fine.

This is the component code

```
    <template>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 mt-lg-5">
          <div class="card bord-rad-5">
            <div class="card-header purple-background top-borders">
              <h4
                class="title-align font-montserrat text-light white-text-color mt-3 position-filter"
              >
                Filter
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                <div
                  class="gray-text-color font-weight-bold font-montserrat-regular mb-2"
                >
                  <h5>{{ $t('labels.frontend.filters.companyName') }}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <b-form-group class="ml-1">
                    <b-input-group>
                      <b-form-input v-model="filter" placeholder="Type to search">
                      </b-form-input>
                      <b-input-group class="mr-2">
                        <b-button
                          class="mr-left-90 mr-4 mt-2 font-montserrat-regular"
                          :disabled="!filter"
                          @click="filter = ''"
                        >
                          {{ $t('labels.frontend.companies.clear') }}
                        </b-button>
                      </b-input-group>
                    </b-input-group>
                  </b-form-group>
                </div>
                <div
                  class="gray-text-color font-weight-bold font-montserrat-regular mt-2 mb-2"
                >
                  <h5>{{ $t('labels.frontend.filters.companyType') }}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline mt-1 mb-1">
                  <input
                    class="form-check-input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="ac1"
                    value="AssemblyCompany"
                  />
                  <label
                    class="form-check-label gray-text-color font-weight-bold font-montserrat-thin"
                    for="ac1"
                  >
                    {{ $t('labels.frontend.filters.dismantling') }}
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline mt-1 mb-1">
                  <input
                    class="form-check-input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="gd1"
                    value="garagebusiness"
                  />
                  <label
                    class="form-check-label gray-text-color font-weight-bold font-montserrat-thin"
                    for="gd1"
                  >
                    {{ $t('labels.frontend.filters.garage') }}
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline mt-1 mb-1">
                  <input
                    class="form-check-input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="rb1"
                    value="RevisionCompany"
                  />
                  <label
                    class="form-check-label gray-text-color font-weight-bold font-montserrat-thin"
                    for="rb1"
                  >
                    {{ $t('labels.frontend.filters.revision') }}
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-5 col-lg-9">
          <div class="card-header purple-background bord-top-lr-5">
            <b-row class="mt-2">
              <b-col>
                <h4 class="title-align font-montserrat text-light white-text-color">
                  {{ items.count }} {{ $t('labels.frontend.companies.results') }}
                </h4>
              </b-col>
              <b-form-group label-cols-sm="3" class="mb-2 w-25 mr-4">
                <b-form-select v-model="perPage" :options="pageOptions">
                </b-form-select>
              </b-form-group>
            </b-row>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body white-bg">
            <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x m-2 border-0">
              <div class="border-0 mb-2">
                <b-table
                  striped
                  hover
                  :items="items.data"
                  :fields="columns"
                  :filter="filter"
                  :current-page="currentPage"
                  :per-page="perPage"
                  :outlined="outlined"
                  responsive
                >
                  <template slot="name" class="m-3" slot-scope="item">
                    <h5 class="title-align font-montserrat" style="color: #5b2557">
                      <a :href="data.item.url" :title="data.item.name">
                        {{ data.item.name }}
                      </a>
                    </h5>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col">
                        <p
                          class="gray-text-color font-montserrat-thin font-weight-bold"
                        >
                          {{ data.item.street }}
                          {{ data.item.building_nr }} {{ data.item.postal }}
                          {{ data.item.city }} {{ data.item.state }}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col ml-lg-5">
                        <p
                          class="font-montserrat-thin blue-light-color font-weight-bold"
                        >
                          T. {{ data.item.phone }}<br />
                          <a
                            :href="data.item.website"
                            target="_blank"
                            :title="data.item.name"
                            class="gray-text-color"
                          >
                            {{ $t('labels.frontend.companies.goTo') }}
                          </a>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col ml-lg-5">
                        <a
                          class="font-montserrat-regular"
                          :href="
                            $app.route('frontend.companies.show', data.item.slug)
                          "
                          style="color: #74aee0"
                        >
                          {{ $t('labels.frontend.companies.moreInfo') }} »
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <button
                      class="mb-3 blue-light-bg btn bord-rad-5 white-text-color font-montserrat-regular"
                      href="#"
                    >
                      {{ $t('labels.frontend.companies.stock') }}
                    </button>
                    <br />
                  </template>
                </b-table>
                <b-row>
                  <b-col md="6" class="my-1">
                    <b-pagination
                      v-model="currentPage"
                      :total-rows="totalRows"
                      :per-page="perPage"
                      class="my-0"
                    ></b-pagination>
                  </b-col>
                </b-row>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'SearchCompaniesTable',
      props: {
        companyName: {
          type: String,
          required: false,
          default: () => ''
        }
      },
      data() {
        return {
          filter: null,
          totalRows: 1,
          currentPage: 1,
          perPage: 10,
          pageOptions: [5, 10, 25],
          outlined: true,
          columns: [
            {
              field: 'name',
              label: 'Name'
            }
          ],
          items: []
        }
      },
      computed: {
        rows() {
          return Object.keys(this.items).length
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        axios.get('/companies/search').then(response => {
          this.items = response.data
          this.totalRows = this.items.count
          console.log(this.fields)
        })
      }
    }
    </script>
    <style>
    .hidden_header {
      display: none;
    }
    thead {
      border: none !important;
    }
    tbody {
      border: none !important;
      border-color: white;
    }
    table {
      border: none !important;
    }
    th {
      border: none !important;
    }
    tr {
      border: none !important;
    }
    td {
      border: none !important;
    }
    .mr-left-90 {
      margin-left: 68px;
    }
    .position-filter {
      position: relative;
      top: -8px;
    }
    </style>
```

could you please help me to find a solution for that ?

Here you can find the code for the component

```
<template>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 mt-lg-5">
          <div class="card bord-rad-5">
            <div class="card-header purple-background top-borders">
              <h4
                class="title-align font-montserrat text-light white-text-color mt-3 position-filter"
              >
                Filter
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                <div
                  class="gray-text-color font-weight-bold font-montserrat-regular mb-2"
                >
                  <h5>{{ $t('labels.frontend.filters.companyName') }}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <b-form-group class="ml-1">
                    <b-input-group>
                      <b-form-input v-model="filter" placeholder="Type to search">
                      </b-form-input>
                      <b-input-group class="mr-2">
                        <b-button
                          class="mr-left-90 mr-4 mt-2 font-montserrat-regular"
                          :disabled="!filter"
                          @click="filter = ''"
                        >
                          {{ $t('labels.frontend.companies.clear') }}
                        </b-button>
                      </b-input-group>
                    </b-input-group>
                  </b-form-group>
                </div>
                <div
                  class="gray-text-color font-weight-bold font-montserrat-regular mt-2 mb-2"
                >
                  <h5>{{ $t('labels.frontend.filters.companyType') }}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline mt-1 mb-1">
                  <input
                    class="form-check-input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="ac1"
                    value="AssemblyCompany"
                  />
                  <label
                    class="form-check-label gray-text-color font-weight-bold font-montserrat-thin"
                    for="ac1"
                  >
                    {{ $t('labels.frontend.filters.dismantling') }}
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline mt-1 mb-1">
                  <input
                    class="form-check-input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="gd1"
                    value="garagebusiness"
                  />
                  <label
                    class="form-check-label gray-text-color font-weight-bold font-montserrat-thin"
                    for="gd1"
                  >
                    {{ $t('labels.frontend.filters.garage') }}
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline mt-1 mb-1">
                  <input
                    class="form-check-input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="rb1"
                    value="RevisionCompany"
                  />
                  <label
                    class="form-check-label gray-text-color font-weight-bold font-montserrat-thin"
                    for="rb1"
                  >
                    {{ $t('labels.frontend.filters.revision') }}
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-5 col-lg-9">
          <div class="card-header purple-background bord-top-lr-5">
            <b-row class="mt-2">
              <b-col>
                <h4 class="title-align font-montserrat text-light white-text-color">
                  {{ items.count }} {{ $t('labels.frontend.companies.results') }}
                </h4>
              </b-col>
              <b-form-group label-cols-sm="3" class="mb-2 w-25 mr-4">
                <b-form-select v-model="perPage" :options="pageOptions">
                </b-form-select>
              </b-form-group>
            </b-row>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body white-bg">
            <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x m-2 border-0">
              <div class="border-0 mb-2">
                <b-table
                  striped
                  hover
                  :items="items.data"
                  :fields="columns"
                  :filter="filter"
                  :current-page="currentPage"
                  :per-page="perPage"
                  :outlined="outlined"
                  responsive
                >
                  <template slot="name" class="m-3" slot-scope="item">
                    <h5 class="title-align font-montserrat" style="color: #5b2557">
                      <a :href="data.item.url" :title="data.item.name">
                        {{ data.item.name }}
                      </a>
                    </h5>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col">
                        <p
                          class="gray-text-color font-montserrat-thin font-weight-bold"
                        >
                          {{ data.item.street }}
                          {{ data.item.building_nr }} {{ data.item.postal }}
                          {{ data.item.city }} {{ data.item.state }}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col ml-lg-5">
                        <p
                          class="font-montserrat-thin blue-light-color font-weight-bold"
                        >
                          T. {{ data.item.phone }}<br />
                          <a
                            :href="data.item.website"
                            target="_blank"
                            :title="data.item.name"
                            class="gray-text-color"
                          >
                            {{ $t('labels.frontend.companies.goTo') }}
                          </a>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col ml-lg-5">
                        <a
                          class="font-montserrat-regular"
                          :href="
                            $app.route('frontend.companies.show', data.item.slug)
                          "
                          style="color: #74aee0"
                        >
                          {{ $t('labels.frontend.companies.moreInfo') }} »
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <button
                      class="mb-3 blue-light-bg btn bord-rad-5 white-text-color font-montserrat-regular"
                      href="#"
                    >
                      {{ $t('labels.frontend.companies.stock') }}
                    </button>
                    <br />
                  </template>
                </b-table>
                <b-row>
                  <b-col md="6" class="my-1">
                    <b-pagination
                      v-model="currentPage"
                      :total-rows="totalRows"
                      :per-page="perPage"
                      class="my-0"
                    ></b-pagination>
                  </b-col>
                </b-row>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'SearchCompaniesTable',
      props: {
        companyName: {
          type: String,
          required: false,
          default: () => ''
        }
      },
      data() {
        return {
          filter: null,
          totalRows: 1,
          currentPage: 1,
          perPage: 10,
          pageOptions: [5, 10, 25],
          outlined: true,
          columns: [
            {
              field: 'name',
              label: 'Name'
            }
          ],
          items: []
        }
      },
      computed: {
        rows() {
          return Object.keys(this.items).length
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        axios.get('/companies/search').then(response => {
          this.items = response.data
          this.totalRows = this.items.count
          console.log(this.fields)
        })
      }
    }
    </script>
```

What mistake i am doing and thank you for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing the code inside the template tag from `<template slot="name"  slot-scope="item">` to `<template v-slot:cell(name)="data">`

Answer (score 0):

In your first code snippet your `style` is not using the `scoped` attribute, which may mean the rest of your project is doing he same thing. This could mean that your CSS is being overwritten at the global level, If you inspect the element after render can you see if your CSS is being overwritten somewhere.

Also, if you happen to be using SCSS the bootstrap-vue library supports it very well and I have found it to be easier to adjust the bootstrap css easier.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it seems the problem related to how i used the v-slot i will provide the solution for it